# Mongo Restore fails to restore time series collection with the same name

Tags: mongodb, collections, time-series, mongodump, mongorestore

I have a timeseries collection in mongodb `liveSamples` collection, I'm trying to dump some documents from this collection and then restore it later with `mongorestore` to the same time series collection `liveSamples`.

The problem is that using `mongorestore` it doesn't allow to restore to an existing time series, so it asks to use `--drop`, but if i use drop ill lose all existing data in the collection.

notice that this works in a normal collection but not in a timeseries colelction.

This works in `mongoexport` and `mongoimport`, but the thing is that im using the capability of `mongodump` and `mongorestore` to compress the documents to `gzip` which is very critical for me.

How can i overcome this?